# Why does the "all actions" user profile tab take so long to load?

Tags: bug, profile-page, activity-tab

Since changing from "activity" to "all actions", it's consistently taking ~5 seconds for this tab to load (when the "all" sub-tab is selected).  Other tabs load instantly.

This only appears to be happening on profiles for which there are a lot of historical actions (for example, Shog9's [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9?tab=allactions))—but I am sure that it wasn't the case prior to the tab's renaming (not that the name itself will be responsible, of course—I just assume some other change occurred at the same time).

I searched, but couldn't find any other report.  Has this gone unnoticed?

Comment: I see the same thing, but only when the "all" sub-tab is also selected.

Comment: @KevinB: Agreed, it is only in that case.  I have added that detail into the question.

Comment: I suspect the issue comes down to having to select all of those different collections of data and then combining them into one giant list. In my case it's 965 pages long. Since selecting each one of them individually is instant, i'd suspect the process that combines them into 1 collection.

Comment: @KevinB: Agreed, but I'm 99% certain it wasn't this slow prior to last week...

Comment: Got an example of a profile where you're seeing this?

Comment: @Shog9: Sure, [yours](http://stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9?tab=allactions) :)

Comment: bad query plan. Nick has fixed temporarily, better fix to come.

Comment: @Shog9 details in an answer for the curious (if possible)?